# Unable to display file in browser angularjs via webapi

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to download a file returned from Web API to angular client. The problem is that the file does not open, i.e pdf the browser displays "failed to load" or for a text file, in the content "undefined". Please view the screen shots for clarity.

I am returning a `HttpResponseMessage` from the server, the response.Content contains `MemoryStream` of a file returned from wcf service.

I am not sure why it is not working, I have tried a number of things suggested on here and looked at some other articles.

I have set responseType to arraybuffer, tried to return `ByteArrayConent`, `StreamContent`.

In the UI, tried to create a blob and file, further more invoking window.URL.createObjectURL and window.open methods as well as trying window.location.href.

In order to rule out if something is wrong with the stream, tested the returned stream in asp.net mvc app and it returns and opens the file as expected in the browser. So the stream coming back from wcf service is ok.

**Server:**

```
public HttpResponseMessage DownloadDocument(string filename)
        {
            var proxy = new WCFService();
            Stream fileStream = null;
            var storage = proxy.GetObject("param", "foo.txt", "param", out fileStream);

            if (fileStream != null)
            {
                var mstream = new MemoryStream();
                fileStream.CopyTo(mstream);
                var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    //Content = new StreamContent(mstream)
                    Content = new ByteArrayContent(mstream.ToArray())
                };

                result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = mstream.Length;
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(storage.ContentType);
                result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachement")
                {
                    FileName = storage.FileName,
                    Size = mstream.Length
                };

                return result;
            }
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

        }
```

**UI:**

```
  $http.get('http://service/api/doc/downloaddoc?filename=null', { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
      .success(function (data) {
         var contentType = 'application/pdf';
         var blob = new Blob([data], { type: contentType });
         var file = new File([blob], 'foo.pdf');
         var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
         window.open(url, 'f');

}
```

**Also tried:**

```
 var reader = new FileReader();
 var out = new Blob([this.response], { type: contentType });
 reader.onload = function (e) {
    window.open(reader.result);
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(out);
```

**Screenshots:**
[image: TextFile]

[image: PDF]

Comment: Why not to simple do `window.open("http://service/api/doc/downloaddoc?filename=null")`?

Comment: how do i pass in bearer token this way? using ouath token authorisation

Comment: Via GET params.

Comment: Actually not directly pass oauth token in GET param. Generate another OPT and pass that token in GET params. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28287491/2509344

Comment: that doesnt seem like a good way of doing it to me for my needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, first the method return type should not have been a HttpResponseMessage instead I needed to return a MemoryStream.

The other problem relating to the HttpResponseMessage was that, the result was wrapped in a ApiController.Ok() method in the web api controller.

So from the web api, I return the HttpResponseMessage. that solves it.

Comment: I am facing the same problem like i attach file stream in http context.response but then from angular end what shall i do i.e how do i pass bearer token in windows.href.location?

Comment: post your question :)